# How can I change image with button or after certain time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a script running that changes the image based on the click on 1 of 5 buttons. It also changes the background of the section.

What is to add that after a certain time like 1 second the images changes automatically to the next one. But only when the first image is in the viewport for the first time.

Is there a way to do that?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#change-image img').removeAttr('srcset');
    $('.wa_button').on({
      'click': function() {
        $('#change-image img').attr('src', '/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/hcg019_wa.png');
        $('.state').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass("active");
        if (!$('.bg-change').hasClass("green blue black gray")) {
          $('.bg-change').removeClass("green blue black gray").addClass("white");
        } else {
          $('.bg-change').removeClass("white");
        }
      }
    });

    $('.ba_button').on({
      'click': function() {
        $('#change-image img').attr('src', '/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/hcg019_ba.png');
        $('.state').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass("active");
        if (!$('.bg-change').hasClass("white gray blue green")) {
          $('.bg-change').removeClass("white gray blue green").addClass("black");
        } else {
          $('.bg-change').removeClass("black");
        }
      }
    });

    $('.mg_button').on({
      'click': function() {
        $('#change-image img').attr('src', '/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/hcg019_mg.png');
        $('.state').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass("active");
        if (!$('.bg-change').hasClass("black blue white gray")) {
          $('.bg-change').removeClass("black blue white gray").addClass('green');
        } else {
          $('.bg-change').removeClass("green");
        }
      }
    });

    $('.sg_button').on({
      'click': function() {
        $('#change-image img').attr('src', '/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/hcg019_sg.png');
        $('.state').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass("active");
        if (!$('.bg-change').hasClass("black blue white green")) {
          $('.bg-change').removeClass("black blue white green").addClass('gray');
        } else {
          $('.bg-change').removeClass("gray");
        }
      }
    });

    $('.pb_button').on({
      'click': function() {
        $('#change-image img').attr('src', '/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/hcg019_pb.png');
        $('.state').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass("active");
        if (!$('.bg-change').hasClass("black white gray green")) {
          $('.bg-change').removeClass("black white gray green").addClass('blue');
        } else {
          $('.bg-change').removeClass("blue");
        }
      }
    });


  });
</script>
```

Comment: Please format (indent) your code properly. There's a Tidy button right in the snippet creator. It's difficult to work with walls of text. We'd also need your HTML.

Comment: You seem to be asking about several things (an event at intervals, and starting a function on element viewport entry). Please revise to ask about just one thing, and show us what you've tried.

Comment: you can call function with `setInterval`and function must check/save does the image show first time.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use setTimeout... 1000 is equal to 1 second
here is an example that will run the function "changecolor" in 1 second from now.

```
function changecolor() {
    $('.bg-change').removeClass("black white gray green").addClass('blue');
} 

$('.pb_button').on({
      'click': function() {
        //.... 
        setTimeout('changecolor()', 1000);
        //.... 
});
```

For more details about the setTimeout function:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Try it out, and let me know if that solved it for you or you need more help.